# Form submission issue in wordpress admin (custom plugin) using $_GET for searching & filtering

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, wp-admin, forms, wordpress.com-hosting

I have a custom plugin that was built by a developer which was working fine until last week Friday. The plugin is running on wordpress.com platform rather than a stand alone Wordpress.org CMS.
An order listing page appearing on edit.php has a filter and search form on it which can be used for filtering the contents appearing on the list page. Technically, when when a search is done or you select your filter option and click on the Filter button, the form input values are submitted to the page URL as parameters, then the page shows the filtered contents.
As of last week Friday(all of a sudden) it stopped submitting form input onto the URL as parameters. Instead, when the filter/or search button is clicked, the page just reloads and nothing happens.

Does anyone have any idea of what could be causing this and how to solve it?

Comment: there's no code or technical details in your question, without these it's impossible to diagnose the problem nevermind solve it. Use the edit link to add code and technical information to your question. That includes related plugins, e.g. you mentioned an order listing but WP doesn't come with an orders post type, so I'm assuming WooCommerce? If so that needs to be mentioned with the other information. If it turns out that the problem requires specific knowledge of a 3rd party plugin to solve though then the question would be offtopic

Comment: You mentioned orders. Are you using WooCommerce? WooCommerce recently updated so that it no longer uses edit.php for orders. You’ll need to have a developer rework your plugin for compatibility or set WooCommerce to run orders in legacy mode. You’ll need to consult WooCommerce support resources for more information on this, as third party plugins are off topic here.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was actually being caused by wordpress.com . Looks like they made an update on their platform which made the search function stop working properly, as the issue was also happening on the default Blog and Page listing section in the admin even when plugins had been deactivated.